# Compiler can't find styles

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

How do I make this error go away...

[image]

Do I need to add a package reference? I'm already referencing this...

[image]

I can't upgrade the package version because... Xamarin.

Comment: Can you check if all the references are referencing correctly also give your VS for mac versioning details

Comment: Try to NuGet restore the solution. It seems that you may have an issue with a nuget getting restored and resources making the build process.

Comment: @JonDouglas I nuked the global nuget folder and restored. Took ages. Now it compiles. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to NuGet restore the solution. It seems that you may have an issue with a nuget getting restored and resources making the build process.